# Is A → B the same as B → A when speaking of functional dependencies?

Tags: database, database-schema, functional-dependencies

This might very simple but I just had to check with you guys.

When it comes to databases, does the arrow in literature imply vise versa on equality?

Meaning, is A →  B considered the SAME as B → A, in particular when it comes to databases and functional dependencies?

Comment: Each username determines a single specific reputation score (at any given time). Does each reputation score determine a single specific username?

Comment: You are not clear. "imply vise versa on equality" is unintelligible. And you don't mean "in particular when", you mean "when".

Answer (score 1):

Please read the reference(s) you were given for FDs (functional dependencies).

A FD is an expression of the form "A → B" for sets of attributes A & B. So if A and B are different, A → B is a different FD than B → A.

For a relation value or variable R, "A → B holds in R" and "A → B in R" say that if two R tuples have the same subtuple for A then they have the same subtuple for B.

Is A → B in R equivalent to B → A in R? If A and B are the same set, then yes. But what if they aren't?

```
X Y
a 1
b 1
```

{X} → {Y} holds in that relation value. {X} <> {Y}. Does {Y} → {X} also hold?