# Is functional dependency in relational database reversible?

Tags: database, rdbms

In relational database if I have two attributes (A and B) which are related by functional dependency A->B. Does this imply that B->A ?
In other words if B is dependent on A , is the vice versa true?

Comment: Why should it or shouldn't it? Please show some research effort. [ask] [help]

Comment: [Is A → B the same as B → A when speaking of functional dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44156101/3404097) Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Suppose we have a table in database which relates teachers to their subjects.
(Teacher->Subject).
This does not mean that we can get the name of teacher with the help of subject because multiple teachers can be teaching the same subject. So, this is a many to one mapping.